# Invisible precedence constraint on SSIS task?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that *appears* to call one task three times that the designer does not indicate.  A recent change in the stored procedure now logs when the task is called.  There are always three entries when the execution path does not pass through it or four when it does.  It contains no loops and three calls are almost always within a tenth of a second or less while when the fourth occurs it tends to be a wider time gap.

[image][image]

I've tried poking around in it as raw XML, but nothing immediately obvious jumps out.  I see the number of references to its key that seem to match the number of incoming and outgoing constraints, only one reference to the called proc and offhand no extra references to the object the proc itself is referenced in.

Is it possible to find all predecessors to/callers of a task?  Is there a better way to identify just what is calling the task?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Control Flow. Then click up on the Package Explorer Tab and expand everything but the Variables, which will exist on every Executable. Screenshot that too and then click the Edit button and add those two caps

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I did spin through the constraints, too, but notice nothing in particular.  I'm going to see if there's a way to pass calling information (constraint, prior task, whatever) to the task...